# Upper bound for the Lipschitz constant of the dual objective function

Tags: least-squares, lipschitz-functions

I need to find an upper bound for the Lipschitz constant of the dual objective function.
The dual objective function I have is
$$max -\frac14 μ^TLL^Tμ+μ^TLy$$

L is a 999x1000 matrix

```
⎡1 −1 0 0 ⋯ 0 0⎤
⎢0 1 −1 0 ⋯ 0 0⎥
⎢0 0 1 −1 ⋯ 0 0⎥
⎢⋮ ⋮ ⋮ ⋮ ⋮ ⋮      ⎥
⎣0 0 0 0 ⋯ 1 −1⎦
```

I know I need to find an upper bound for the norm of $LL^T$

And use the following property in connection with $||Lx|| _2^2$ $\le$ $4||x|| _2^2$ $$ \lambda _{max} (A) = max(x^TAx : ||x||^2 = 1) $$
Where A is a positive semi-definite symmetric matrix and its 2-norm is given by its largest eigenvalue $\lambda _{max} (A)$

Can you please give me a step by step method from how to go from the first equation to a bound for the Lipschitz constant of the dual objective function.